# Breaking while loop, reaching a certain randomly generated value in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

Writing a while loop in R.

I have an initial value and I need to simulate a sample (size must be unlimited though, not 100).

When a sample hits a necessary value, I would like to break the loop and print a message.

My logic is the following:

```
my_start <- 1000 # inital value
random <- sample(my_start, size = 100, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) 
# sample simulation, but size must be not 100, but unlimited
while (result > 2000) {
result <- my_start + random # trying here to add a sample to initial value
print('Start reaches', result)
}
```

Plus I would like the distribution of the sample would not exceed 100.

I appreciate any tips!

**UPDATED:** Almost reached the goal with the help of another user, just want that the fluctuation of value would not be more than a certain value (100), not purely random. For instance, it will fluctuate between 900 and 1000 and when it hits 1050, it will break.

```
my_start <- 1000 # inital value
result <- my_start
n <- 2000 # generate random number from 1 to this value

while (result < 2000) {
random <- sample(n, 1)
result <- random
cat('\nValue reaches', result)
}
```

Comment: What are you sampling from? `sample(my_start, size = 100, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)` means any random number from 1 to `my_start` with `size` of 100. Is that what you want?

Comment: @RonakShah, my_start = 1000, I need to generate random numbers until it will be equal to 2000. Plus I would like the distribution of the sample would not exceed 100. Then I need to break the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaly, this is what you want :

```
my_start <- 1000 # inital value
result <- my_start
n <- 100 #generate random number from -n to n

set.seed(123)
while (result < 2000) {
  random <- sample(-n:n, 1)
  result <- result + random
  cat('\nValue reaches', result)
}

#Value reaches 1058
#Value reaches 1136
#Value reaches 1049
#Value reaches 1143
#Value reaches 1212
#...
#...
#Value reaches 966
#Value reaches 906
#Value reaches 980
#Value reaches 969
#Value reaches 928
#Value reaches 843
#Value reaches 858
#...
#...
#Value reaches 1952
#Value reaches 1973
#Value reaches 2015
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost! I also would like randomly generated value could go below 1000 and I would like to have an unlimited loop (not size = 100) until I reach 2000.

Comment: @Oleksiy It is already an unlimited loop and not restricted to any specific size. I have added adjustments to increment/decrement value.

Comment: thanks! Almost there! How to limit the randomness to a certain fluctuation? Please see the updated question.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the new edit of your question means. However, please don't change your question after you have received an answer. Include all the details and expected behavior in your original question itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I updated, but did not change anything! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I figured it out! n <- c(900:1000). Perfect, thanks!